# In java, when using regex to find patterns, how to get nested result?

Tags: java, regex, overlapping-matches

The case is that, I want to find string which satisfies "c+d" in a string "cccd".
My code is as follows,

```
String str="cccd";
String regex="c+d";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher =pattern.matcher(str);
While(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group())
}
```

The result is only "cccd". But what I want is to get all the possible results, including nested ones, which are cd, ccd and cccd. How should I fix it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried matcher.group(2) ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228384/finding-all-of-the-matching-substrings-not-only-the-most-extended-one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Use a lookahead to capture the overlapping characters,

```
(?=(c+d))
```

And finally print the  group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE0iR5/3)

Your code would be,

```
String str="cccd";
String regex="(?=(c+d))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher =pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
cccd
ccd
cd
```