# How could I use regular expression to match all the satisfied string in the text?

Tags: java, regex

I use the pattern like `(J|N){1}N` to match the text like `JNN`.

Using this pattern I can only get the `JN` in the text. However I want to get both the `JN` and `NN`

How could I get all the substring which satisfied the pattern?

If the text is like `JNNNN...` Is there a convenient way to get all the matched string?

Comment: Why not `JN+`?. I'm confused, what are you trying to match? What's your pattern?

Comment: That will get the longest one. But the term length is fixed. Pattern is (J|N){1}N.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228384/finding-all-of-the-matching-substrings-not-only-the-most-extended-one

Comment: Try clarifying with a better example.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **Positive Lookahead** to capture the overlapping matches.

```
(?=([JN]N))
```

Example:

```
String s  = "JNNNNJNN";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=([JN]N))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
JN
NN
NN
NN
JN
NN
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this website out, it is indeed handy:

http://www.regexr.com/

For JN and NN, what you are looking for is

> /[J|N]N/g

This will indeed match JN NN NN in JNNNNNNN....

I hope that helps.

[image]